# jq in CLI create error when I want to parse the output

Tags: jq, slug, home-assistant

Using Home Assistant 0.92 to test my CLI for creating automated backuping. After a successful backup, the command responds with an output and I need to catch that value. I'm trying to use jq to parse it but only get an error.

```
$ hassio snapshots new --name"Testbackup"
```

This gives an output of `slug: 07afd144` and I want to catch `07afd144`

Tried following:

```
$ hassio snapshots new --name"Testbackup" | jq --raw-output '.data.slug'
```

This gives an output of `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5`

The final result is planned to be:

`slug=$(hassio snapshots new --name="${name}" | jq --raw-output '.data.slug')`

where `${slug}=07afd144`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `slug: 07afd144` isn't JSON, which explains why `jq` fails to parse it. `cut -d' ' -f2` might be enough (split over space, take second part)

Comment: @Aaron, sorry to ask - I'm quite noob to jq -  could you please provide me with a full example of your suggested solution?

Comment: The solution I propose is `slug=$(hassio snapshots new --name="${name}" | cut -d' ' -f2)` and doesn't rely on `jq` since the input format isn't JSON. It assumes the output of the `hassio` command will always conform to the format `slug: whatYouWant` with a space after the colon

Comment: @Aaron Thank you! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

`slug: 07afd144` isn't valid JSON and as such cannot be parsed with `jq`. Furthermore, it doesn't contain a `data` property anywhere, so `.data.slug` doesn't make sense.

If the format is always this simple (property name, colon, space, value), then the value can be easily extracted with other common tools generally available on GNU+Linux systems:

- `cut` (different invocations possible):

  ```
  cut -d' ' -f2-
  cut -c7-
  ```
- `awk`:

  ```
  awk '{print $2}'
  ```
- `sed`:

  ```
  sed 's/^slug: //'
  ```
- `perl:

  ```
  perl -lane 'print $F[0]'
  ```
- or even `grep` (different invocations possible):

  ```
  grep -o '[^ ]*$'
  grep -o '[[:xdigit:]]*$'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`jq` is a tool for parsing and transforming JSON documents. What you have shown is not legal JSON. It is however a legal YAML document and can be transformed with [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/). `yq` uses jq-like syntax, but can handle JSON, YAML, XML, and CSV files.

```
slug=$(hassio snapshots new --name="${name}" | yq '.slug')
```